# Deserialize JSON message in run time

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deseralizse  a JSON message in run time and extract the values then assign to variables.

```
 dynamic Json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
```

This is value deserialised in Json variable which I found in debugger

```
{{
  "geo": [
    {
      "x": 16324865.646724658,
      "y": -4967300.1743641077
    }
  ]
}}
```

I'm getting error when I tried to assign the parsed message into variables.

```
  double x1 = 0;
  double y1 = 0;

      
  x1 = Json.geo.x.Value();
  y1 = Json.geo.y.Value();
```

Error Message:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'x''
```

Comment: geo is a list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  double x1 = 0;
  double y1 = 0;

      
  x1 = Json.geo[0].x;
  y1 = Json.geo[0].y;
```

Try the above once?

Comment: Thanks mate. It gave me an error but it worked after removing the value() method.

Answer (score 0):

This has fixed the issue.

```
double x1 = 0;
double y1 = 0;

      
  x1 = Json.geo[0].x;
  y1 = Json.geo[0].y;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).